# Python SQLite3 multiple variables in SELECT

Tags: python, sqlite

I am trying to do something like this

`cur.execute('''SELECT ID FROM ? WHERE Name = ?''', (var1,var2) )`

but got a error message of syntax error near "?"

I have also tried

```
 cur.execute("SELECT ID FROM" + var1 + "WHERE Name = ?", (var2,))
```

same error happened

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't use placeholder for names of columns or tables.

The second example fails because of missing spaces. Correct to:

```
cur.execute("SELECT ID FROM " + var1 + " WHERE Name = ?", (var2,))
```